# Хранится ли в памяти переменная ссылочного типа?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять хранится ли ссылка в принципе в памяти? Смущает тот момент, что мы ее объявляем - а это значит, что технически мы резервируем под нее место в памяти. С другой стороны не инициализированных ссылок не бывает. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И что вас здесь смущает? В любом случае для данных нужна память, в которой они будут храниться, будь то stack, heap или где-то еще.

Comment: *"а это значит, что технически мы резервируем под нее место в памяти"* - ничего подобного, ссылки не являются объектами, соответственно под них не обязательно выделяется место для хранения. А если оно и выделяется, то не обязательно доступное для пользователя. В данном случае взятие адреса берет адрес объекта, а не ссылки. Также не следует приводить текст картинкой.

Answer (score 6):

Если сократить ответы на [аналогичный вопрос на en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179937/how-does-a-c-reference-look-memory-wise), дела обстоят так:

0. Стандарт языка только описывает, как ссылка должна себя вести.
1. Из п. 0 следует, что конкретная реализация ссылки полностью лежит на плечах разработчика компилятора, он может *разворачивать* ссылки на этапе компиляции (то есть, заменять их на то, куда они ссылаются), если у него это получится, а может и хранить их явно в памяти
2. Если компилятор избрал явное хранение ссылки в памяти, она займет столько же места, сколько указатель. Но это не точно - см. п. 1.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `int a ;` с автоматическим местом хранения. Это значит, что **если** берётся адрес переменной и передаётся другой функции, то компилятор выделит место в памяти *под своё усмотрение* и передаст адрес. Если компилятору нет необходимости для выделения памяти этой переменной, то вполне без выделения памяти он этот код сделает.

У переменной типа ссылка программист не имеет права взять его адрес. А если попытается, то получит адрес куда указывает эта ссылка. То-есть расположение ссылки в памяти полностью зависит от компилятора. Он может хранить в стеке, в глобальной константной переменной *(адреса ссылки)*, или вшитыми адресами в коде.

```
int a = 5;
int & aref = a ;
```

Если вы попытаетесь вывести на экран адрес переменной `a`, то этой переменной выделиться место в стеке. А если выводите адрес ссылки, то выведится адрес этой-же переменной `a`. Место куда хранить ссылку не понадобиться. И скорее всего эта ссылка будет служить просто синонимом переменной `a`.

Comment: В программе ТС (по крайней мере откомпилированной g++) никакой памяти под ссылку выделено не будет. Кстати, рассматривать ссылки как синонимы это совершенно правильно, именно так и следует всегда (ну, в большинстве случаев) поступать

Comment: Есть обязательные условия для выделения памяти, это структура. `struct { int & l ; } ;` - место для ссылки будет. @avp Так-что слово **понадобиться** не зря написал.

Comment: @AlexGlebe к сожалению, вы ошибаетесь - Clang может выкинуть в том числе и структуру - https://godbolt.org/z/d9P6Yq6er

Comment: Нет, не выкинул.  https://godbolt.org/z/74jcc5YPv @gbg

Comment: @AlexGlebe все же, структурой он не пользуется - он сразу кладет в eax константу 42.

Comment: Да, g++ (без оптимизации) хранит структуру с ссылкой (8 байт на 64-bit компе), например, если печатать ее адрес

Comment: @avp - Если структуру не трогать, то есть, например, не печатать ее sizeof(), то ничего и храниться не будет.

Comment: @gbg, естественно. А если ее потрогать, то можно и ссылку изменить

Comment: @avp в ответ на это компилятор потом может так потрогать - костей не соберем.

Comment: @gbg, не ходи к гадалке. Поэтому С++ это плохой язык, лучше им не злоупотреблять