# Почему у меня получилось определить указатель на ссылку?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

я второй день учу c++ и читая книгу увидел фразу

"Поскольку ссылки не объекты, у них нет адресов, а следовательно, невозможно определить
указатель на ссылку." книга c++ primer 5 издание.

на сколько я понял ссылки нужно сразу же инициализировать. и вот я написал небольшой код:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
  int i = 0, &r1 = i;
  int *p = &r1;
  std::cout << p << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

0x7ffce0596274

так что получается я определил указатель на ссылку?
объясните и поправьте меня если я не прав, пожалуйста.

Comment: если вы выведете еще и `&r1`, то увидите, что `p == &r1`

Comment: `int i = 0, &r1 = i;` : `r1` - это ссылка на объект `i`. Взятие адреса `& r1` выдаст адрес `i`. А получить адрес самой ссылки не получится. смотрите [Хранится ли в памяти переменная ссылочного типа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1327169/Хранится-ли-в-памяти-переменная-ссылочного-типа/1327190#1327190)

Comment: Если бы можно было определить указатель на ссылку (т.е. место, где она хранится в памяти), то ссылку можно было бы переназначить, чтобы она ссылалась на что-то другое, а это не так...